# Отправить сообщение и ждать ответа

Tags: javascript, mqtt

Как я не хотел работать с `javascript`, но пришлось.

Вопрос к знатокам: есть ли возможность отправить запрос (кастомный,  из `paho js` клиента через mqtt), а потом дожидаться ответа (ответ тоже является сообщением mqtt-протокола)? Вопрос даже не касается, как такового протокола mqtt. В общем, есть ли решение для javascript узнавать сработала та или иная функция или произошло то или иное событие с учетом времени начала работы функции?

**Логика**

1. Отправляю сообщение от клиента No1
2. Запускаю таймер
3. Жду 5 сек
4. Если пришло обратное сообщение от клиента No2, то вывожу `ok`
5. Если не пришло обратное сообщение от клиента No2, то `not ok`

В любом случае приложу, то чем сейчас пользуюсь

На данный момент имею полностью рабочего клиента `paho js`. Соответственно, отправка и прием сообщений возможны в любых видах, но использую JSON.

**Что имеем**

функция для подключения к mqtt-брокеру

```js
'onConnect': function() {
  websocketclient.connected = true;
  this.subscribe(websocketclient.mac);
  console.log("Connected!");
  setInterval(function() {
    websocketclient.render.connectionPing();
  }, 30000);
},
```

и функция для отправки pinga другому клиенту

```js
'connectionPing': async function() {
  let mes = {
    connected: 1
  }
  websocketclient.publish(websocketclient.mac + "/command", mes);
},
```

из кода видно, что я отправляю каждые 30 сек запрос. И после отправки запроса я и хочу проверять получил ли я обратное сообщение в течении 5 сек или нет. Это возможно?

Comment: Смотрю используете скобочную нотацию для обращения к свойству объекта. `["connected"]: 1` или `data["mid"]`, но по большому счету это нужно только для вычисляемых значений или для строк с разрывами или Symbol. Можно было просто `"connected" : 1` => `connected : 1`. А обращаться с помощью точечной нотации: `websocketclient.connected` или `this.connected` внутри самого объекта.

Comment: действительно работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для контроля за временем выполнения процессов принято вызывать `performance.now()` и
сравнивать результат `then - now`. Результат измеряется в миллисекундах, но с гораздо бОльшей точностью нежели вызов: `new Date()`

```js
let image = new Image();
let time = performance.now();
image.src = "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/gradient-grainy-gradient-shape-set_23-2148971570.jpg";
image.onload = () => {
  document.body.append(image);
  let time_passed = performance.now() - time;
  console.log("Time passed: " + time_passed); 
  console.log("Less than 5sec?: " + !!(time_passed < 5000));
}
```

Или вызвать функцию `setTimeout`, ожидающую какое-то время и устанавливающую   флаг `time_is_over = true`, который определяет стоит ли выполнять какие-то действия после прихода опоздавшего ответа.
Если сообщение пришло раньше, то `clearTimeout`.

```js
let image = new Image();
image.src = "https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/person-putting-medical-mask-earth_23-2148984685.jpg";
    
const TIME_TO_WAIT = 5000;
let time_is_over = false;

let waiting = setTimeout(() => {
    sendMessage('not ok');
    time_is_over = true;    
}, TIME_TO_WAIT)

image.onload = () => {
    if(!time_is_over){
        clearTimeout(waiting);
        sendMessage('ok');
        document.body.append(image);
    }
}

function sendMessage(message){
  console.log(message);
}
```

**Здесь заведомо меньшее время на загрузку изображения:**

```js
let image = new Image();
image.src = "https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/person-putting-medical-mask-earth_23-2148984685.jpg";
    
const TIME_TO_WAIT = 50; // ЗДЕСЬ!!
let time_is_over = false;

let waiting = setTimeout(() => {
    sendMessage('not ok');
    time_is_over = true;    
}, TIME_TO_WAIT)

image.onload = () => {
    if(!time_is_over){
        clearTimeout(waiting);
        sendMessage('ok');
        document.body.append(image);
    }
}

function sendMessage(message){
    console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: Отлично. думаю, что использование флагов, для меня - более очевидное решение. Поскольку у меня объект для работы с брокером единственный, для него и определю поле с флагом и буду его переключать в зависимости от вызванной функции)

Comment: Не то чтобы это другое решение, просто из вопроса не сразу понятно в чем именно загвоздка: вычислении разницы времени, хранение данных вне функции, сам синтаксис JS или принятые практики использования setTimeout))))))

Comment: все из выше перечисленного. Я старался избегать javascript до последнего, но не удалось. По моему синтаксису может понятно, что я пытаюсь быть в ООП, но насколько это удается мне не ведомо) `websocketclient()` является объектом с константами и функциями. За его пределы и не буду выходить. Я даже не уверен, что понятия для javascript в моем объяснении верны))) Ваше решение я и буду использовать. Моя благодарность

Comment: реализовал, ответ - рабочий вариант

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь, спасибо за обратную связь!